# DB Design for Schedule

Tags: sql, mysql, database, database-design

I'm creating a web application wherein users should be able to specify their weekly schedule. Here's my DB model for that:

```
id
user_id
day
from
to
```

`day` is an enum of 0-6 (0 for Sunday, 1 for Monday, and so on). `from` and `to` represent minutes from midnight. So, 0 means midnight, 1 means 12:01am, 2 means 12:02am, etc.

Is this a good design? Any potential problems with it?

What if I wanted the ability to display more than a week? How would I handle that? Right now, I'm just displaying weekly work schedule, but it might be nice to be able to specify more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I think where the other answerers are getting off track is that they're trying to design a perpetual calendar.  I think you only want to design a system that shows the regular, repeating weekly schedule for, for instance, a worker.

For that use, a regular, repeating weekly schedule, your design is okay.  I would make FROM and TO into TIME columns rather than integers, but that's about it.

If you intend to track the amount of time people *actually did work* you will have to implement a second table for that more along the lines of what the other users have mentioned.

Comment: No tracking of the amount of time people actually did work is needed. I just need to add/edit/delete a weekly schedule. The schedule is indeed "regular, repeating weekly schedule." Think of a brick & mortar store that has its operating hours displayed on a window -- that's what I **need**. The ability to have a "perpetual calendar" would be nice, but not a requirement.

Comment: Your design is good for that purpose (except I'd use TIME instead of INTEGER).  In that context I don't understand what "displaying more than one week" means, there _is_ only a single week in this design.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, you have a design for a single file (it is not a database or data model by any stretch of the imagination), and you realise it is very limited.  You have many questions and you have posted with a database tag.  You would like to implement it in a database or "database", but you are not interested in learning about the capabilities of databases.  In addition when you get two good database people answering, you simply argue with them, and continue to think your enums and bits are better ...  but you cannot even make a schedule that spans weeks or years.  Which such contradictory behaviour, how is anyone supposed to help you ?

1. Raw File.
   Now there is no problem with your enums and limited capability file, just keep it on your C drive. When you want speed, just load it into arrays in memory.  After all, it is a closed system completely wrapped in, and limited to, a single developer.
2. Database.
   If you want database capability (search, integrity, recoverability), then by all means place it in a database.  You can provide an open (secured but open) database, so the users can interrogate the database without having to through your app; without being limited to the functions provided by your app.  Eg. create any report they want with any report tool.  Most people have found that that results in less coding for them.  For that, you need to read up and learn databases.
   .
   .
   Databases have concepts such as Domains and Datatypes.  The need for them, to be able to host consistent functions above and beyond the data itself was determined 40 years ago, and provided in standardised form over 30 years ago.  Let me provide one example.  An enumerated integer alleged to contain a day number is not useful to anyone except you, and it very very limited thinking (note that from your questions, even you realise there are limits to any kind of navigation outside a single week).  ANSI SQL provides a DATE and DATETIME Datatype.  .
   .
   If you use them:

   - anyone can inspect your date columns easily
   - and more important, they can perform date arithmetic and comparisons on them, using Date Functions that are provided with the database software, without any need to go through your app
   - Further, **you** can use those same functions and features in your app, and eliminate the time you spend coding them.
   - All your questions and limitations are eliminated. (You will still have to read up on how that is so; how to display Date Formats, perform Date Arithmetic ... much like using a library).
     .
3. Raw File Located in Database.
   If you place your file in a database, without learning about databases, their capabilities, data modelling techniques, then you would still have a file limited to your limited capability.  It remains a file with no database capabilty, only that it is located in a database platform somewhere.  Locating a file of enums in a database does not magically anoint it with database capabilities (placing normalised and compliant structures in a database does).  All your questions and limitations will remain.

Now, granted, a DATE or DATETIME column may have more components in it, than an enum TINYINT, and to you today, it might look "inefficient", but only because you do not understand all the Date Functions that can be performed on such columns.  Once you have "enhanced" your single-digit enum to provide some of the Date functions you yourself require, let alone what users expect and demand, it will be as fat and wide as a standard DATETIME column, if not more. What is more likely is, you will end up implementing multiple fields (not columns), as each requirement dawns on you, all of which together will be vastly more inefficient, and which can be replaced with a single DATETIME column.

Last, and Dave is quite correct, you will never, not in 20 lifetimes, even remotely approach the Date handling functionality in your app, that the vendors have already provided in theirs.  I won't be able to approach that either.  Therefore, please do not reinvent the wheel.

Consider the requirements, and choose which option you want and let us know, so that we can help you.  Unless you genuinely want [2], please remove the Database tag.

=================================

**Responses to subsequent comments**

1. Thanks.  Questions are easy to answer.  Statements re things you do not know, are, well,  argument.
2. Yes, there are serious limitations in your approach. You can't provide just one weeks schedule. A week does not exist in isolation: it exists in the context of a month, a year, a month of a year, etc. Your week does not allow a booking to go from Fri to Tue. Even for the week proposed, It does not supply a week completely. And yes, it cannot be expanded or enhanced to provide more than the fixed week. Which is why everyone is proposing a DATE; that will release your week from its shackles. There is much more that you need, for a reasonable schedule, but you have not asked that question.
3. Date.  If you bothered (it is all in the manuals and available online) to read up on the `DATE/TIME/DATETIME` Datatypes, you will find: it contains all date_parts; you use just the date_parts you want (eg. DayOfWeek) and default the others; it lets you do Date Arithmetic and comparisons on *all* date_parts (eg. DayOfMonth), without your concerns.  Obviously, you should not perform such operations on the Date components that you did not consciously set.  Let's call your "table" WeekSchedule:

```
CREATE TABLE (
    -- I cannot see the need for an "id" so it is excluded
    UserId        INT           NOT NULL,
    MeetingName   CHAR(30)      NOT NULL,
    StartDateTime SMALLDATETIME NOT NULL,
    EndDateTime   SMALLDATETIME NOT NULL,
    ...
    )
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX UC_PK
    ON WeekSchedule (UserId, StartDateTime)
    -- double bookings eliminated, in addition to providing decent key
```

Eg. set StartDateTime to default todays date and the meeting start time; EndDateTime to default todays date and the meeting end time.  Since you've loaded HH:MM only, do not inspect YY.MM.DD or DoW or DoM or WoY.  In the meantime, others can inspect it using:

```
    DATEADD(date_part, integer, date_expression)
    DATEDIFF(date_part, date_expression1, date_expression2)
    DATEPART(date_part, date_expression)
    DATENAME(date_part, date_expression)
    -- RTM for further details 
    -- Dave has already provided example display formats
```

etc, without having to ask you what the content is, whether 1 means Sunday or Monday, whethr you use military time notation or an analogue face, etc.

Later, when you implement the structures and tables required to support cross-week meetings (or a monthly schedule, or recurring meetings), you will find that WeekSchedule already supports that, no structural change necessary; simply load the StartDateTime columns with the actual meeting start date and time; the EndDateTime with the actual meeting end date and time.

Comment: you have mistaken my "request for clarification" for "arguing". I have asked the question because I do realize there is potentially a problem with my approach. What apparently I am not making clear (or not understanding from the proposed solutions) is that I really only need to represent 1-week's schedule (Sunday to Saturday, no particular date). The "What if I wanted the ability to display more than a week?" question was to point out that my solution (which I think works for what I need) won't work if I wanted to expand later on.

Comment: With regards to the proposed solutions of using Date, I still don't see how I can attach a date to a Sunday-Saturday schedule. There is no year, month, or day (e.g. 13th) information associated with the information I am trying to store. I don't understand how I can use Date.

Answer (score 2):

On a first thought I would try to make the design a bit more open. Something like

```
id
User_id
Date
Start_Time
End_Time
```

This way you do not limit yourself to one week. Besides, working with dates and times makes it easier to do calculations. Having them it is pretty easy to get the day of the week, minutes from midnight, etc.

Using this you can also easily get the week number which would allow you to show the user their schedule by just choosing the week of the year and/or its start dates.

This design supposes you will not have schedules starting on a day and ending on the next one. In that case you would need a Start_Date and an End_Date.

Hope this helps

Comment: I need to show a weekly schedule. That is the primary goal. With your design, how would I show `Monday, 9am-5pm`? I don't see this as a date at all. My design can handle schedules starting on a day and ending on the next one: it simply needs to make 2 entries.

Comment: Generally speaking I have to agree with Dave. The design you proposed is a closed one which makes difficult to introduce changes in your app. In my humble opinion it is better to just store the raw data you need (datetime fields) and use datetime functions (which almost every database has) to convert to weekdays, extract hours and minutes or whatever you need. In your design you would need to create your own functions to manage all that and introduce unnecessary complications. Also, with your design you would have it hard to compare different weeks while Dave's or mine make it much easier.

Comment: +1 Nice, simple answer. Dave's edited answer includes examples of the `DATE_FORMAT` function to return both day of week and time values from datetime fields.

Comment: the user can't use DATETIME because (I think) he's trying to design a single weekly schedule per worker rather than a perpetual calendar.  In other words, MON the worker is scheduled from 9am to 3pm and again from 6pm to 8pm.  That's every single Monday, not just a particular one.

Comment: @Larry, I understand he wants to show a week schedule, but he also wants the ability to show more than 1 week. He explicitly asks how he could show such data (guess for a 2-week or month schedule) and that excludes that all Mondays have to be the same. Either way, using date fields makes both versions simpler to create and manage than using adhoc types and functions.

Answer (score 1):

Please don't reinvent the wheel. This is one of the most powerful thinking on programming and developing anything.

What I mean here is, everytime you have the possibility to rely on built-in or native type, you should use it. On fields **day**, **from** and **to**, you can and should consider using appropriate native types, like **Date**, **Datetime**, **Timestamp**.

Also, if you need retrieving, filtering and so forth on these data, you can use built-in functions.

This kind of thinking on design can improve reliability on data, and make you programming easier, hence you count on functions and data types proper, tested, and widely adopted.

I would do this database like:

```
id -- autoincrement
Start -- datetime
End --datetime
```

I suppose you have a Users table. And I would add one more table, UsersSchedule, like:

```
user_id -- FK to users
schedule_id -- FK to schedule
```

Thus, many users can be registered to the same meeting or event. Of course, this can go even further, and add other control fields like EventName, EventPromoter (user_id from proponent user), Invites(user-id list of people invited to event), Atendees (user_id list of people who confirmed/atended the event)... but this decision is up to you.

Note that I would heavily use DateTime functions (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html) in order to save on logic programming, like *check today's events scheduled for a particular user*, *conflicting events for a particular user*, and so on.

Well, I think you got the idea.

**EDIT**

Supposing you have one entry like:

```
id   |        start        |        end
45   | 2010-10-25 09:00:00 | 2010-10-25 18:00:00
```

You can run the query:

```
SELECT CONCAT(
DATE_FORMAT(start, '%a'), ', ',
DATE_FORMAT(start, '%l%p'), ' - ',
DATE_FORMAT(end, '%l%p')
) as Event FROM schedule WHERE id = 45;
```

Which will give you the following output:

```
Mon, 9AM - 6PM
```

Done.

Comment: I have the same question for you as I had for Guillem: how do I represent `Monday, 9am-5pm`? All I have is day of week and time range. I don't think that translate to a date.

Comment: I think you didn't get my point right. I didn't tell to NOT USE programming for absolutely nothing, but rely on safe types and functions you can. Well, but if you really want that, you can (despite at this point I disagree with this approach). Along with DAYOFWEEK and time range you can also count with DATE_FORMAT (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function. You can use it with other functions. See my edit.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused with your example. What is the significance of `2010-10-25`? Yes, that's a Monday, but I am not interested in that specific Monday; I am interested in all Mondays. An example schedule would be like this: "Every Monday from 9am-6pm" (there is no specific date attached to it).

Comment: Check your question. You wrote "What if I wanted the ability to display more than a week? How would I handle that? Right now, I'm just displaying weekly work schedule, but it might be nice to be able to specify more.". I gave you something more specific, abstract and powerful. I'm not sure about your application.

Comment: But even not so sure about your application (and thus, one good design to point), if you want not use dates, keep at least the concepts I showed with time fields and functions to make your design and life easier. Using "2" to represent 12:02 AM isn't a good design, hence you have better options to do it.